# How do 'dereferrer' services work?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I recently came across a URL shortening service called [t1p.de](http://t1p.de) that offers 'derefer(r)ing' of URLs. Finding that intriguing I thought I'd try that myself. Using chrome's debug/develop view [F12] it tells me that the website is using a '301 - permanently moved' http redirect.

Using Spring I wrote a small Controller that returns a `RedirectView` which is the Spring equivalent/way of doing a `http 301` redirect.

Checking again using chrome's dev tools though I see that I can still see the original referer in the request header.

**How does this service and/or any other service manage to replace the referer?**
**How could I accomplish this in java using `Java EE` technology and/or `Spring`?**

Comment: [`RedirectView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) seems do respond a 303 (*See Other*), not 301 (*Moved Permanently*). This may be the issue? Try to play with [`@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html).

Comment: @sp00m interestingly it returns a `302` for me now. Although I am sure that it returned a `301` when I wrote the question.

Comment: @sp00m nvm, you can use `setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVERD_PERMANENTLY)` to change the response code from `302` to `301`. Although that does not change anything regarding the referer hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 'derefer(r)ing' is basically a *hack*. One easy way to do it (and the only one I found) is to add header information to the returned html page, directing the browser to immediately *refresh* and call a new page:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://google.com" />
</head>
```